# What does the "verify" function in RSAKey (AS3Crypto) does?

Tags: c#, .net, actionscript-3

I really don't understand what the _verify function does in this class :

http://code.google.com/p/as3crypto/source/browse/trunk/as3crypto/src/com/hurlant/crypto/rsa/RSAKey.as

And especially what does it put into the 'dst' variable. I actually have a "verify key" wich use this method on an encrypted data, and I get the public key in the dst variable...

Here is a small diagram, so that you understand better: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rNL2Z.png

Thanks

Ps : I have to do the same in .net,so if you know something equivalent, let me know it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function _verify (included for reference below)

```
    public function verify(src:ByteArray, dst:ByteArray, 
length:uint, pad:Function = null):void {
        _decrypt(doPublic, src, dst, length, pad, 0x01);
    }
```

Looking at the [link](http://code.google.com/p/as3crypto/source/browse/trunk/as3crypto/src/com/hurlant/crypto/rsa/RSAKey.as) you supplied, the function is used to verify RSA signed data  - the result is copied to the dst ByteArray.

Breakdown:

- `doPublic` = function parameter, a wrapper around `BigInteger.modPowInt()`
- `src` = byte array with signed data
- `dst` = byte array which will hold the result of with verification result
- `length` = length of the data in src byte array
- `pad` = function parameter, a wrapper for `pkcs1pad` (`_encrypt`) and `pkcs1unpad` (`_decrypt`)
- `0x01` = padType - an integer value specifying if a fixed value (`0xff`) is used in padding (0x01) or a pseudo-random one (0x02) - (only actually used in `pkcs1pad` which is called from `_encrypt`)

In the RSA scheme, signed data is verified by decrypting the signature using the public key.

**Update:** Unless you have very specific needs which are not covered, is see no reason why you want to port the ActionScript-3 you posted. Use the c# [RSACryptoServiceProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rsacryptoserviceprovider.aspx) which is included in the framework. Take special note of the section `Interoperation with the Microsoft Cryptographic API (CAPI)` in the MSDN description.

Addressing your comments about needing the content of the `dst` byte array in a similar manner to the AS3Crypto implementation you could just create a wrapper to decrypt the signed data against the public key. Have a look at [RSACryptoServiceProvider.ImportParameters()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rsacryptoserviceprovider.importparameters.aspx) function which you use to import the public key information. Since you haven't provided details as to how the public key is retrieved I can't be more specific. This implementation [example](http://www.jensign.com/opensslkey/opensslkey.cs) should help with parsing key files to create appropriate `RSAParameters` to feed to the `ImportParameters` method.

Comment: Ok, thanks alot for this complete answer! :) Now i have to found a similar .net function.

Comment: @user1913003 - why port the script - have a look at RSACryptoServiceProvider (link included in updated answer).

Comment: The problem is that I need the 'dst' variable, and the VerifyHash & VerifyData functions in RSACryptoServiceProvider only returns booleans.

Comment: @user1913003 updated the answer with a possible workaround which could address your needs.

Comment: Thanks, I tried to decrypt the signed data with the key, but I don't get a valid RSA key from it.

Comment: That's a different problem. Consider asking a new question, supplying your code, example (public) key data and expected output, so that this question does not get sidetracked.

Comment: Ok, here's [the new topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14012836/verify-an-encrypted-rsa-key-in-c-sharp)